# using multiselect widget options are not showing for select

Tags: jquery, widget

I am new at jquery. I used multi select widget for more than one selection in select box my code is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#nefirst-choice").change(function(){
             $("#nesecond-choice").load("nontelecom/"+$(this).val()+".html");
        });

        $("#nesecond-choice").multiselect();
    });
</script>
</head>
   <body>
      <select id="nefirst-choice" name="nontelname0"> 
          <option selected value="none">Please Select</option>
           <option  value="A10Networks">A10 Networks</option>      
           <option  value="Acision" >Acision</option>
           <option  value="ADB">ADB</option>
      </select>

      <select id="nesecond-choice" name="nsub10" multiple>
           <option value="none">Please choose from above</option>
      </select>
   </body>
</html>
```

so if I drop `$("#nesecond-choice").multiselect();` it works perfectly but showing normal multi select box which i don't want.

I am not getting what i did wrong and how to correct that.